# Getting column names and null value counts from df.info() pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame called `df`:

```
df = { 
     'a' : [1, NaN, 2, NaN] },
     ...
     'b' : [1, 5, 6, 6] 
}
```

I want a list of tuples, each tuples containing: `(column_name, #_non_null values_for_that_column)`

Using `df.info()`, I am able to visualize the number of non-null < dtype >s. I would like to programmatically loop through the column names and the non-null value counts in a fashion similar to how I'd loop through a df or a dict:

```
for column_name, non_null_count in ?:
    ...
```

How do I get this from the `df.info()` call? **Note: I know how to get this from the DataFrame, curious specifically about `df.info()` return value.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`pd.Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
                   'b': [1, 5, 6, 6]})

res = list(df.isnull().sum().items())
# [('a', 2), ('b', 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: *Use a string buffer (io package) to load the object returned by .info(). Once loaded, basic python operations can get you what you need.*

Code:

```
# Buffer functionality
import io
# Regular expression functionality
import re

buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)

# If you look at the output, the first 3 lines and the last 2 lines describe the output. There will be one trailing '' (hence -3).
# Shrink multiple spaces into one space, to be guaranteed that each split value is as such: split_arr[0] == column_name, split_arr[1] == non_null_count 
tuple_array = [
    (re.sub(' +', ' ', val).split(' ')[0], re.sub(' +', ' ', val).split(' ')[1]) 
    for val in buffer.getvalue().split('\n')[3:-3]
]
```

Output: The output from the sample DataFrame above would look as follows. Note, this code can be applied to any `df.info()` call.

```
tuple_array = [
     ('a', '2'),
     ...
     ('b', '4')
]
```